# Wrong usage of MVC @helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I made a helper which is meant to help me debug my app.

It firsts display a header.
Then it tries to run a block of code which returns a fews arguments (array of objects).
Those arguments are used in a string format which is displayed when the block ran fine.
If the block caused an exception, the exception gets displayed.

The problem is, nothing gets displayed at all when I call the helper (I'm very new to that feature).

What's wrong?

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using MygLogWeb.Classes.Fox

<span>test</span>

@helper TryMethod(
    string header
    , Func<object[]> act
    , string successFormat
)
{
    @Html.Raw(String.Format(
        @"<h2>{0}</h2>"
        , HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(header)
    ));

    try
    {
        var args = act();

        if (successFormat == null)
        {
            @Html.Raw(@"<span class='Success'>OK</span>");
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.Raw(String.Format(
                @"<span class='Success'>{0}</span>"
                , HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(String.Format(
                    successFormat
                    , args
                ))
            ));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exe)
    {
        @Html.Raw(String.Format(
            @"<span class='Error'>{0}</span>"
            , HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(exe.Message)
        ));
    }
}

<span>test</span>

@{
    TryMethod(
        "Cust.Columns"
        , () => {
            return new object[]
            {
                Cust.Columns.Count
            };
        }
        , "Count: {0}"
    );
}

<span>test</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with the helper method itself but with the execution.

When you execute like this:

```
@{
    TryMethod(...);
}
```

the code is executed but it's a code block but not written to output.
Use this syntax instead:

```
@(TryMethod(...))
```

this should work.